# Drop unchanged rows after concate operation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which I need to concate based on Id column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4], 'Quantity':[10,20,30,40], 'Price':[100,80,90,150]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3], 'Quantity':[10,25,20], 'Price':[100,75,90]})

pd.concat([df1.set_index('Id'), df2.set_index('Id')], axis=1, keys=['X','Y'])
```

With this operation, I am getting result as:

As the data in first is unchanged between two dataframes, I should not get this row in my output, i.e output should not contain rows which are unchanged.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the rows where "X" and "Y" are the same:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Id'), df2.set_index('Id')], axis=1, keys=['X','Y'])

>>> df[df["X"].ne(df["Y"]).any(axis=1)]
          X              Y      
   Quantity Price Quantity Price
Id                              
2        20    80     25.0  75.0
3        30    90     20.0  90.0
4        40   150      NaN   NaN
```

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you for quick response.